# .Net compatability with SQL Server 2014

Tags: .net-4.5, sql-server-2014

I am very new to SQL programming and I wish to work with SQL Server 2014.
Can someone please tell if SQL Server 2014 is compatible with my current configuration:

- Visual Studio 2010
- .NET 4.5.51209 SP 1

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is compatible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appear to be compatible.Thanks to marc_s for his answer.